# split a string variable through shell script

Tags: linux, shell, tcl

i have a string containing date and time as **timestamp= 12-12-2012 16:45:00**

I need to reformat it  into **timestamp= 16:45:00 12-12-2012**

How to achieve this in shell script?

Note Please : variable's value is **12-12-2012 16:45:00** and **timestamp** is the name of variable

```
#!usr/bin/expect
set timestamp "16:45:00 12-12-2012"
Now what should i do so value of timestamp will become 12-12-2012 16:45:00
script extention is .tcl example test.tcl
```

Comment: is `timestamp` the actual environment variable, or part of the value?

Comment: @Keith its a local variable

Comment: So, you are actually trying to take the value of the variable `timestamp`, which is `12-12-2012 16:45:00`, and swap only that part, right?

Comment: @Keith :  Yes thats right i need that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*\)\([ \t]*\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/' input
```

this command works on lines containing the pattern `number-number-number whitespace antyhing`.  It simply swaps the `number-number-number` part `\([0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*\)` with the `anything` part `\(.*\)`, also keeping the original whitespaces `\([ \t]*\)`. So the replace part of sed is  `\3\2\1`, which means the third part, white spaces, and the first part.

Same logic with tcl:

```
set timestamp "12-12-2012 16:45:00"
set s [regsub {([0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*)([ \t]*)(.*)} $timestamp \\3\\2\\1]
puts $s
```

Comment: :will this work in tcl script also ? and i need to use above as : **sed 's/\([0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*\)\([ \t]*\)\(.*\)/\3\2\1/' timestamp** can you tell me how this **sed** command is working here?

Comment: The parens grab the part that matches...they count from left to right. So, the first thing grabbed is in \1, next in \2, etc. The / delimits the pattern to match from the replacement string.

Comment: @perreal : it's not changes its printing the same value as before

Comment: @perreal yes it works but please check the orignal question **date /time** has to be changed in to **time/date** you just did reverse, and can you explain the working also :)  **2012-12-12 20:20:20** to **20:20:20 2012-12-12**

Comment: Same logic - pick the bits to swap with a regular expression and swap them as strings - but in two languages. Note that the Tcl example uses the wrong input string, and writes it to a different variable, but works on the right one and can be witten back to `timestamp` just as easily.

Answer (score 4):

You could use variable patterned removal. ## means "greedily remove everything that matches the pattern, starting from the left". %% means the same from the right:

```
tm=${timestamp##* }
dt=${timestamp%% *}
result="$tm $dt"
```

or you could use cut to do the same, giving a field delimiter:

```
tm=$(echo $timestamp | cut -f2 -d' ')
dt=$(echo $timestamp | cut -f1 -d' ')
result="$tm $dt"
```

or you could use sed to swap them with a regex (see other post).

or if you are pulling the date from the date command, you could ask it to format it for you:

```
result=$(date +'%r %F')
```

and for that matter, you might have a version of date that will parse your date and then let you express it however you want:

```
result=$(date -d '12/12/2012 4:45 pm' +'%r %F')
```

admittedely, this last one is picky about date input...see "info date" for information on accepted inputs.

If you want to use regex, I like Perl's...they are cleaner to write:

```
echo $timestamp | perl -p -e 's/^(\S+)\s+(\S+)/$2 $1/'
```

where \S matches non-space characters, + means "one or more", and \s matches spaces. The parens do captures of the parts matched.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, didn't realize that the "timestamp=" was part of the actual data. All of the above example work if you first strip that bit out:

```
var='timestamp=2012-12-12 16:45:11'
timestamp=${var#timestamp=}
... then as above ...
```

Comment: Note the clarification to the question.

Answer (score 1):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution here:

```
string="timestamp= 12-12-2012 16:45:00"
awk '{print $1, $3, $2}' <<< "$string"
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash (and similar shells):

```
$ timestamp="12-12-2012 16:45:00"
$ read -a tsarr <<< "$timestamp"
$ echo "${tsarr[1]} ${tsarr[0]}"
16:45:00 12-12-2012
```